# Android DatePickerDialog accent color (in v21+)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

I'm using the support library 21 for my app. My theme is also defined in **values-v21**, but the `DatePickerDialog` doesn't use the accent color for the background and text color.

What can I do to change this color to the accent color?

My current themes.xml are

values/themes.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

values-v21/themes.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AlertDialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The app theme defines a default dialog theme. You'll need to extend this theme to include your accent color.

Comment: @alanv I've added my current (partly working) themes to my original post. Can you see my mistake for the DatePickerDialog?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your dialog theme needs to extend `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` instead of `Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert`. Here's an example:

```
<!-- Base Theme Styles -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- my theme stuff -->
    ...

    <!-- dialog theme stuff -->
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.DialogTheme</item>

</style>

<!-- Styles for pop-up dialogs -->
<style name="AppTheme.DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>

</style>
```

Comment: @kaftanati not true, this works if using appcompat v21. You just need to omit the 'android:' prefix in the colour items.

Comment: But I used support-appcompat v7 ofr all devices (8+).

Comment: works. But i can't figure out how to change the "active color". For example Datepicker, mark a day and it's using a different color from those set in the style above.

Comment: @DanielBo use this:  <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item> inside AppTheme.DialogTheme to style it